# Generating function of a random walk

Tags: probability, independence, random-walk, moment-generating-functions

Consider a random walk with $S_n=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$, where the random i.i.d. steps $X_i$ take values $-1,0,2$ with probabilities $1/9,1/9,7/9$ respectively. Set $S_0=1$.

I would like to calculate the probability generating function of $S_n,G(T)=E(T^{S_n})$.

Here's my attempt:

$$G_{S_n}(t)=E(t^{S_n})=E\left(\prod^n_{i=1}t^{X_i}\right)=G_X(t)^n$$

Where independence of $X_i$ was used, and

$$G_X(t)=E(t^X)=1+\frac{1}{9}t^{-1}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{7}{9}t^2$$

Would this be correct?

Comment: wait why does $E[t^X]$ have a $1+$?

Comment: Is your $S_n$ meant to be $1+\sum$  (So we can pretend there is no $S_0=1$ ) ?

Comment: i guess your acceptance of my answer answers my questions on your question XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your $S_n = 1 + \sum$ for $n\ge1$. Then I believe $$G_{S_n}(t) = E(t^1) [G_X(t)]^n = t[G_X(t)]^n, G_X(t) = \frac{1}{9}t^{-1}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{7}{9}t^2$$